# If $var is empty dont work?

Tags: php

I run this code:

```
<?

$map = do_shortcode('[codepeople-post-map]');    
if (empty($map)) {echo '<br />'; } else {echo $map;}

?>
```

**The problem** is when the $map is empty it won't echo the `<br />`

I have tried this 2 methods to see if $map is really empty:

- `echo $map;`        // It results empty and noting is shown on page.
- `var_dump($map);`   // It results: `string(937) " "`

**My question** is what does `string(937) " "` means and how can I make my code work?
I tried also:

```
<? if ($map == string(937) " ") {echo '<br />'; } else {echo $map;} ?>
```

But no success so far this last code is wrong and just gives error.

Comment: How about using `isset` instead of `empty`?

Comment: @JunM: Using `isset` do echo `<br />` if $map contains a space. But on other hand it wont echo if $map contains my map values.

Comment: @Vikas: `is_null` gives me the same results as `empty`

Comment: @Cyborg Where does `$map` came from?

Comment: @JunM: `$map = do_shortcode('[codepeople-post-map]');` using WordPress plugin GoogleMaps

Comment: @Cyborg I can't help you much on wordpress but I believe there something wrong in inserting the map. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Your variable is a string with a space, which evaluates to `TRUE`, so it is not empty.

Instead of using `empty()`, you might check if `trim($map) === ''`.

Comment: or just trim($map) == ''

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means that you have a string with a space in it.
Probably the var was previously a string which was emptied wrong. One solution I could suggest you, depending what your application's purpose is.

```
 if(trim($map) == "" || $map == null)
 {
      echo "<br />";
 }
 else
 {
      echo $map;
 }
```

Because actually it only means that the string contains a whitespace (this explains why there is a space in " "). You should try to locate where you get the $map value and try to put some verifications there.

Alex

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't make any difference on the page. It shows if the MAP is there and otherwise it still DONT do `<br />`

Comment: I might suggest you to look and show us what is the return type of do_shortcode(); . If you can find that we'd be able to advance further